# Why i cannot install homerun launcher?

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, ppa

After install Kubuntu(I forgot how much I've reinstalled the OS),I've installed [Homerun](https://launchpad.net/~blue-shell/+archive/homerun) launcher many times, but since yesterday evening reinstall i couldnt find a way to install it, no package installer is finding it.

I tried, sudo apt-get install homerun, sudo aptitude install homerun, tried from ubuntu software center and muon software center,nothing.

None are finding it,I installed the ppa,updated all the stuff, 3 times did it and still no software.

Comment: The https://launchpad.net/~blue-shell/+archive/homerun has homerun packages for the Quantal and Raring. You have tag 12.04 = Precise.

Comment: ouch, yeah it seems they updated it,lol i installed it on 12.04 a week a go 2013-01-28-updated, thank you for enlightnement

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by downloading the debian packages from [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~blue-shell/+archive/homerun/+packages) and installing them manually,1 by 1,even tough they are for quantal.Answered in case anyone else is trying to installing homerun launcher on 12.04.